# polyfill for CSS3 'calc()' under webkit?

Tags: css, webkit, polyfills

Many of us have been thrilled with polyfills to make IE less of a drag. But my beef is with WebKit. What the hell, WebKit? You're so awesome at everything else; why did you have to go and not implement calc(), eh? ...but it's not a big deal if there's a polyfill.

Is there?

Google is uncharacteristically laconic on this point. So: 0 Hivemind, does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 3):

calc() support has landed in Chrome 19 with the -webkit- prefix! Not sure how long before version 19 gets pushed out to everyone, but it should be within the next few months. Since IE9+ and Firefox already have support, the last holdouts will be Safari and Opera. Fortunately I believe an updated Safari build is likely to be released with OS X Mountain Lion this summer. I'm not sure when Opera plans to add support.

Comment: What about the friggin' Android browser.. stupid Google.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a polyfill for this for Chrome yet ... none that I have found.  Best way to get what you need I think is to use javascript.  Unfortunately you will have to call that script on browser resize as well.

Comment: Looks like this is on the webkit radar though.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16662

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/CJKay/PolyCalc

This is a good start. They have stopped maintaining the project due to most browsers haveing calc available but works well. I have found a couple bugs and fixed them on my sites.

If anyone would like to know my fixes please contact me